# Using for each to create react components within another component

Tags: reactjs, list, loops, foreach

Suppose I have some data for car listings, I want to represent each of these listing object using a react component defined as "VehicleListing". And I want to render each of the listings inside another react component called "VehicleTypes".

Below I am trying to use the forEach method to accomplish that but for some reason, the forEach method won't render anything onto the DOM. Does anyone know why? Also, is potentially there a better way of accomplishing this same task?

Thank you!

```
let Cars = [
  { year: 2013, model: "A", price: "$32000" },
  { year: 2011, model: "B", price: "$4400" },
  { year: 2016, model: "B", price: "$15500" },
];

function VehicleListing(props) {
  return (
    <ul>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <th>Year</th>
          <th>Model</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Buy</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>{props.data.year}</td>
          <td>{props.data.model}</td>
          <td>{props.data.price}</td>
          <td>
            <button>Buy Now</button>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </ul>
  );
}

function VehicleTypes(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{props.vehicleType}</h2>

      {Cars.forEach((listing) => {
        return <VehicleListing data={listing} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

function ReactTransportationApp(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <PageTitle />
      <ChooseOptions />
      <VehicleTypes vehicleType="Cars" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Array.forEach` only returns `undefined` so it's no use here. From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> forEach() executes the callback function once for each array element;
>   unlike map() or reduce() it always returns the value undefined and is
>   not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the
>   end of a chain.

You need to use [`Array.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
function VehicleTypes(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{props.vehicleType}</h2>

      {Cars.map((listing) => {
        return <VehicleListing data={listing} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

... and you don't even need to explicit return statement if you remove the braces, so it can be written slightly more tersely:

```
function VehicleTypes(props) {
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>{props.vehicleType}</h2>

          {Cars.map(listing => 
             <VehicleListing data={listing} />;
          )}
        </div>
      );
    }
```